# How to bind the class name of an element to a changing parameter

Tags: vue.js

In my code I have an increment button like so that works as expected with my counter variable set to zero at the start.

```html
<div id="count">
        <div>{{counter}}</div>
        <v-btn @click="increment">Increment</v-btn>
</div>

<script>
...
  data () {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.counter++
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

I then have an unordered list of items and I would like to bind the classname of the list items so that they change as the value of counter is updated. My isReached function is shown below.

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
       <li v-for="i in noOfMilestones" :key="i" v-bind:class="isReached(key, counter)"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
isReached (key, counter) {
  if (counter >= (this.toReach / this.noOfMilestones) * key) {
    return 'active'
  }
  return ''
}
```

The problem is that the class name is set initially to ' ' as the function is run the first time but as I increment my counter the class name never changes. How can I dynamically bind my classname to the changes in the counter variable?

Comment: Should `isReached(key, counter)` be `isReached(i, counter)`? If not, where does `key` come from?

Comment: key comes from the key set in the list element I believe. It's basically set to i

Comment: That's not how variables work. You want to use `i` in any JS expression. There should actually be an error in your browser console if you use `key`

Comment: You're right, there was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a method within your templates rendering is not efficient (see [Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)).

This looks like it can be done with a simple [class-binding object expression](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

```html
<li v-for="i in noOfMilestones" :key="i" 
  :class="{ active: counter >= toReach / noOfMilestones * i }"></li>
```

Demo...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    counter: 0,
    toReach: 10,
    noOfMilestones: 5
  }),
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.counter++
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: grey;
}
li.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="count">
    <div>{{counter}}</div>
    <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
      <li v-for="i in noOfMilestones" :key="i" :class="{ active: counter >= toReach / noOfMilestones * i }">
        {{i}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```